# Flex 4: Is it possible to have a BorderContainer automatically size to the contents within it?

Tags: size, height, width, flex4, containers

I have a BorderContainer with several objects inside of it. I want it to fit snugly around its own contents, but it doesn't. It seems the default size of a BorderContainer is 112x112. That is so wierd considering no other containers have that default size. Is there a way to set the width and heigh properties to "auto" or something like that?

Comment: bummer.. i'm having the same problem.. annoying. going back to using vbox and hbox

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is BorderContainerSkin that defines the minimal size to 112 pixels.
Workaround : set the properties minWidth and minHeight of your BorderContainer to 0.